# Loading a Big Plist File

Tags: objective-c

I have a big plist file, I have a problem, when I do:

```
 [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docDirPath];
```

I must waiting for some seconds before I can use the application. Is there some solution?

Thanks

Comment: load it in a background thread so it doesn't block the UI

Comment: Had the same issue, so I ended up splitting the PLIST up into several logical files, and load as needed. And I'm thinking of re-factoring using CoreData.

Comment: Thanks Eimantas I'm trying it!

Comment: Martin I think it is the same :| but I'm no sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the plist in another thread, GCD is perfect for this.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ [self.theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docDirPath];   });
```

If the class of the method that does this will not live until the plist read is complete you will need to wrap the block in a copy to Heap.

```
dispatch_async(queue, [[^{ [self.theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docDirPath]; } copy] autorelease]);
```

Comment: I have this warning: Instance method dictionarywithcontenentoffile: not found

Comment: I copied your call just to show the use of GCD.  Just wrap the code you would otherwise use in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

If the plist is stored as a text plist, convert it to a binary plist instead. They load much faster.

The easiest way to do that is with plutil:

> plutil -convert binary1 file.plist

(This assumes that it's a static plist file rather than one created on-the-fly. Within your app you can store a dictionary as binary using NSPropertyListSerialization)